# Twitter video not rendering in webview

Tags: android, html, video, twitter, webview

I get `tweet blockquote` in the description . I create a `html` document and appened `blockquote` and `twitter script` and load that `html` to  `webview`. All the tweets and videos renders properly. Only problem is, When i click on the video, it shows a black screen. This happening for all twitter videos in `kitkat` devcies. Works fine in lollypop and above. I know there is a bug in API level 16 and 17 and videos won't play in the webview. But from API level 18, videos in webview must play and all other videos are playing in the webview in these devices. Only the twitter videos are not working. Below is my html content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <head> 

<script async src ="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" 
charset="utf-8"></script></head> <body><blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-lang="en"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Goodbye <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/Sarbjit?src=hash">#Sarbjit</a>.Gratitude to <a href="https://twitter.com/OmungKumar">@OmungKumar</a> <a href="https://twitter.com/Vanita_ok">@Vanita_ok</a> <a href="https://twitter.com/SandeepSinghOne">@SandeepSinghOne</a> <a href="https://twitter.com/RichaChadda_">@RichaChadda_</a> <a href="https://twitter.com/kirandeohans">@kirandeohans</a> <a href="https://twitter.com/hashtag/AishwaryaRai?src=hash">#AishwaryaRai</a> CREW <a href="https://t.co/1tC4CiCwBN" target="_blank">pic.twitter.com/1tC4CiCwBN</a></p>&mdash; Randeep Hooda (@RandeepHooda) <a href="https://twitter.com/RandeepHooda/status/709620030510600192">March 15, 2016</a></blockquote></body> </html>
```

This is my webview code:

```
public static void setupWebview(WebView webView) {
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        webView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
    }
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);

    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
    android.webkit.CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
}
```

What might be the issue here. I googled a lot, but couldn't get any solution. Is anyone else also, facing similar issue?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19928706/how-to-correctly-embed-tweet-inside-android-webview/53154537#53154537

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Twitter video not loading android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49978021/twitter-video-not-loading-android-webview)

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue.For me it is working on JellyBean(4.1.2) and Lollipop and above,but fails to load on KitKat(API 19). I was checking the logs from the webview by overriding onConsoleMessage method of WebChromeClient and noticed that I am getting the following error after it tries to load the video resource:

> Uncaught InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that
>   is not, or is no longer, usable.

Check your logs and try to debug what step is failing when trying to render the video.

Comment: Even I'm getting the same log. Did you fix this issue?

Comment: No,I am not able to fix it. It looks like some problem with handling loading of resources relative to the base URL. From CommosWare's comments on this question :
http://stackoverflow.com/q/23932708/6065015